# django Model form with initial and data values

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to set my model form with data as well as initial_dict. They both are working fine indivisiually, but when i put both in the method call, Initial does not work.

here is the code.

```
state = Territory.objects.filter(abbreviation=request.GET.get('territory', ''))
    if state:
        initial_dict['state'] = state.get()

ctx['add_customer'] = AddCustomer(data=request.GET, initial=initial_dict)
```

But the state (Dropdown) does not get selected.

This works fine

```
ctx['add_customer'] = AddCustomer(initial=initial_dict)
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually solved my problem.

```
initial_dict = request.GET.dict()
    state = Territory.objects.filter(abbreviation=initial_dict.get('state', ''))
    if state:
        initial_dict['state'] = state.get()
    ctx['add_customer'] = AddCustomer(initial=initial_dict)
```

Converted data to Python Dict & use only `Initial`.

I am still not sure why that problem was occurring.